# Is a finite index subgroup of a finitely presented subgroup finitely presented?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

I do know Schreier's theorem, which states that a finite index subgroup of a finitely generated group is finitely generated. Other than this, I have no reason to suspect a positive answer to my question, other than it would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a consequence of the Reidemeister-Schreier algorithm. 
See Chapter 2, Proposition 4.2 in [1] or Chapter 2, Corollary 2.8 in [2]

[1] Lyndon and Schupp, Combinatorial group theory. Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete, Band 89. Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York, 1977. xiv+339 pp.

[2] Magnus, Karrass and Solitar, Combinatorial group theory. Presentations of groups in terms of generators and relations. Second revised edition. Dover Publications, Inc., New York, 1976. xii+444 pp.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed true. Because being finitely presentable is a geometric property. More precisely "being finitely presentable" is preserved under quasi-isometries and a subgroup of finite index is quasi-isometric to the big group.

Comment: Why is finitely presentable preserved under quasi-isometries? (My knowledge of geometric group theory is basically none, beyond the very basic definitions.) This is a really cool answer though!

Comment: That's a theroem. See e.g. 8.24 Proposition, p. 143 in Bridson, Haefliger "Metric spaces of non-positive curvature". (this book is available online and I highly recommend it, in particular if you are not familiar with geometric group theory)

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are, finite index subgroups of finitely presented subgroups are finitely presented. In fact it is known that if a group is quasi-isometric to a finitely presented group, then it is finitely presented (finite index subgroups are quasi-isometric).

This is proved in *[Lectures on geometric group theory](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/eprints.html)*, by Cornelia Druţu and Michael Kapovich, which is still in the works, but as it is now, it is Cor 6.40. The idea is sketched in *Topics in geometric group theory* by de la Harpe too, V.A.3.